# Convert dataframe to unnamed list

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` looking like this

```
    A     B     C     D
1   78    12    43    12
2   23    12    42    13
3   14    42    11    99
4   49    94    27    72
```

I need the first two columns converted into a list which looks exactly like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] 78 12

[[2]]
[1] 23 12

[[3]]
[1] 14 42

[[4]]
[1] 49 94
```

Basically what

```
list(c(78, 12), c(23, 12), c(14, 42), c(49, 94)
```

would do. I tried this

```
lapply(as.list(1:dim(df)[1]), function(x) df[x[1],])
```

as well as

```
lapply(as.list(1:nrow(df)), function(x) df)
```

But thats slightly different. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: How pedantic are you going to be about the absence of names in the resulting list? e.g. `split(df[,1:2],seq_len(nrow(df)))`

Comment: @joran very. I need it exactly as I described.What the `list()` would do to various vectors...

Comment: Then do what I suggested and `unname` it twice, once with `lapply` and once at the top level.

Comment: There's probably a cleaner way to do it: `out <- lapply(split(df[,1:2], seq(nrow(df))), function(x) as.numeric(x)); names(out) <- NULL`

Comment: @joran where would I do the two `unnames`?

Comment: I take it back, you can do `mapply(c,df$A,df$B,SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` if you really can't have the names.

Comment: @Swarch thats it. I am having big troubles understand `plyr`... Thanks!

Comment: @Stophface No one has mentioned anything from the `plyr` package. But based on your comment you might want to read Joran's lovely answer about [R grouping functions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7141669/903061).

Comment: @joran is there a way to do that with `double` as well? My numbers in my rows are not `integers` but actually `double`

Comment: @Stophface Huh? What do doubles have to do with anything?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the `Map`:

```
Map(c, df$A, df$B)
[[1]]
[1] 78 12

[[2]]
[1] 23 12

[[3]]
[1] 14 42

[[4]]
[1] 49 94
```

Answer (score 0):

In case this is of interest, it is possible to accomplish this with the `foreach` package:

```
library(foreach)
foreach(i=seq.int(nrow(df))) %do% (c(df[[i]][1], df[[i]][2]))
```

`foreach` returns a list by default. The code runs down the rows and pulls elements from the first and second columns.

An even cleaner to read version:

```
foreach(i=seq.int(nrow(df))) %do% (df[[i]][1:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is with `lapply`

```
lapply(seq_len(nrow(df1)), function(i) unlist(df1[i, 1:2], use.names=FALSE))
#[[1]]
#[1] 78 12

#[[2]]
#[1] 23 12

#[[3]]
#[1] 14 42

#[[4]]
#[1] 49 94
```